# How to select a date less than the current one?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I want to load the appointment history of my customer from db, each record have the `start_datetime` and `end_datetime`, actually my query looks like this:

```
$query = $this->db
        ->select('*')
        ->from('appointments')
        ->where('id', 5) 'id of record to select
        ->where('start_datetime' ) 'here's indecision
        ->get()->result_array();
```

essentially the record to load should be all record previoulsly of current datetime. How I can pass this condition in the where clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); # get current time stamp
$query = $this->db
        ->select('*')
        ->from('appointments')
        ->where('id', 5)
        ->where(start_datetime <= $now ) # Sometimes date($now)
        ->get()->result_array();
```

Comment: I can do something like this ` ->where(start_date <= date(Date.Now) ` ?

Comment: @SalvatoreFucito for that i have better solution. wait

Comment: @SalvatoreFucito check now

Comment: @SalvatoreFucito happy to help :)